# Pick recently selected colors in java

Tags: java, swing, color-picker

I would like to add a color picker dialog to my app that remembers recently selected colors, so that it's easy to pick the exact same color as before, instead of getting several slight variations of a color.

I've tried but I couldn't do this with the standarard JColorChooser. JColorChooser has a recent-color panel in some look&feels (motif), but not in others (gtk). Also, there doesn't seem to be a way to prepopulate the set of recent colors, so there is no way to remember state.

What I would really like is an open source library with a better swing-based color picker solution. It has to be compatible with Java 5.

Comment: Have you tried using the ColorSelectionModel? You can access this using myColorChooser.getSelectionModel().  Once you get the ColorSelectionModel you can do something like Color selectedColor=myColorSelectionModel.getSelectedColor() and myColorSelectionModel.setSelectedColor(selectedColor).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the Tutorial's section "[Creating a Custom Chooser Panel](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html#chooserpanel)"?  It looks like to can create a custom panel of saved selections either as a new panel or as part of other panels.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793916/jcolorchooser-save-restore-recent-colors-in-swatches-panel). It should solve your problem on one operating system but probably it will break the L&F for multiple platforms.