# How Do You Change The Color on The Swatches Component of JColorChooser?

Tags: java, jpanel, jcolorchooser

I'm trying to make a drawing application involving JColorChooser Swatches Component, and I'm trying to make my UI a certain color. I was able to change the color through setting the background pretty much everywhere except for one small area around the "Recent" box.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTFbw.png)

Any help would be appreciated, I'll paste part of my code below for context:

```
 //Sets up color chooser
  chooser = new JColorChooser(Color.BLACK);
  AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels = chooser.getChooserPanels();
  for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
     if (!panels[i].getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("Swatches"))
         chooser.removeChooserPanel(panels[i]);
     else {
        panels[i].setBackground(new Color(0, 155, 228));
     }
  }
  chooser.setPreviewPanel(new JPanel());
  //Sets up size slider
  sizeSlide = new JSlider(1, 45);

  //Adds Color/Size to one control panel, adds new panel to bottom of 
  //main
  optionP = new JPanel();
  optionP.setBackground(new Color(0, 155, 228));
  optionP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  optionP.add(sizeSlide, BorderLayout.EAST);
  optionP.add(chooser, BorderLayout.WEST);
  this.add(optionP, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JColorChooser: Save/restore recent colors in Swatches panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793916/jcolorchooser-save-restore-recent-colors-in-swatches-panel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done without some sophisticated search through the JComponent tree. But even than I was not able to change the background color.

EDIT:
I finally managed to change the background color for the recent panel with below code:

```
JColorChooser chooser = new JColorChooser(Color.BLACK);
AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels = chooser.getChooserPanels();
for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    if (!panels[i].getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("Swatches")) {
        chooser.removeChooserPanel(panels[i]);
    } else {
        panels[i].setBackground(new Color(0, 155, 228));
        // placing code to change recent panel background color here
        // will not work for some odd reason
        // JComponent component = (JComponent) panels[i].getComponent(0);
        // component.setBackground(new Color(0, 155, 228));
    }
}
AbstractColorChooserPanel panel = chooser.getChooserPanels()[0];
JComponent component = (JComponent) panel.getComponent(0);
component.setBackground(new Color(0, 155, 228));
```

Another approach worked but it will change the background of all your Panels across the application. Use the UIManager to change the Background:

```
UIManager.put("Panel.background", new ColorUIResource(0, 155, 228));
```